# Grant Symfony2 www-data connect SSH

Tags: php, symfony, ssh, apache2, command-line-interface

i'm blocked with a really sad issue... Since some hours...

Here's the problem :

I tried to create a Symfony2 webapp which needs to connect through ssh protocol on many servers.

I use a Symfony2 command which I call from :

```
$process = new Process('ssh root@'.$ipInput.' apache2 -v');
```

(where $ipInput is an IP address set as first argument on the SF2 command)

If I call my Command crom CLI with check:apache:install, it's ok, because I use it with root.

But if I try to launch that command from a page by calling the Controller with this code :

```
$kernel = $this->get('kernel');
$application = new Application($kernel);
$application->setAutoExit(false);

$input = new ArrayInput(array(
   'command' => 'check:apache:install',
   'ip' => '192.99.36.205',
));

$output = new BufferedOutput();
$application->run($input, $output);

$content = $output->fetch();
echo $content;
```

It returns me :

> Host key verification failed.

What i've tried :

- Create a www-data password to be able to connect with su www-data, and create a .ssh/ directory on /var/www/ home directory and generate ssh-key, put the id_rsa.pub on the remote server... I'm able to connect to root@remote_server with www-data with any password or something like that, but when I launch it with my web browser through the Symfony2 application, it doesn't works.
- I read many pages from Google, but none of them helps me.

I know that is very greedy to let www-data connect through SSH but I don't know how to check if some packages are installed on remote servers.

To be clear, I have near from 15 remote servers already in production and many future servers. And for each server I need to check the web environment before launch an automatic installation of a LMS.

If someone has an idea to do this without grant ssh access to www-data, I will listen very seriously.

I don't want to install a PHP script on each remote server and call them with HTTP request or something like that.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: have you tried with public key export?
ssh-copy-id could be a nice place to start.

Comment: create public key and deploy it on the remote server didn't change anything.

Comment: Try copy your id_rsa used for the root to the webserver hosting this page.
Or specify your identity key with ``ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa www-data@$input-ip``

Answer (score 0):

> Create a www-data password to be able to connect with su www-data, and
>   create a .ssh/ directory on /var/www/ home directory and generate
>   ssh-key, put the id_rsa.pub on the remote server... I'm able to
>   connect to root@remote_server with www-data with any password or
>   something like that, but when I launch it with my web browser through
>   the Symfony2 application, it doesn't works.

You need to specify the identity with your ssh command
assuming your id_rsa is at `/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa`

`ssh -i '/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa' root@remote_server`